# Asymmetrical Half-Bridge Flyback Converters Simulation issue

Tags: power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, simulation, flyback, synchronous

I am using SIMPLIS to construct an Asymmetrical Half-Bridge Flyback Converter. Additionally, I am attempting to implement Synchronous Rectification on the secondary side. Please refer to the schematic below.

[image]

In order to observe the effects of parasitic capacitors on the secondary side, I have included the C5 capacitor with a value of 500pF in my schematic. However, I have encountered an issue during the simulation.

Upon adding this capacitor, I noticed a ringing phenomenon in the Lm component. However, I am uncertain whether this ringing is expected or not. The paper I referred to did not provide a voltage waveform for Lm, which has left me confused. If you have any insights or comments regarding this matter, please let me know.

If I have done anything wrong in my schematic please also let me know.

[image]

I also use SIMPLIS to build up a non-Synchronous Rectification version, and the waveform is what I thought.

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not a flyback converter.

Comment: @Andyaka this is Asymmetrical Half-Bridge Flyback Converter

Comment: I would recommend to replace some of the inductor by their *lossy* version which include parasitic resistances (place>magnetics>Lossy Inductor). These resistances will provide damping to your circuit.

Comment: @VerbalKint Please see my update.
I follow your method to use a loss version inductor. and the resistance value is 300m, but I think the ringing time is still too long and the peak-to-peak value is too large.

Comment: @VerbalKint Do you think this phenomenon is normal when I use SR on the secondary side?
the VLm has a large peak-to-peak ringing, I try to increase the loss resistor, but it is still large.

Comment: In reality, all passive elements include losses (ESR, dielectric for a cap., core and copper losses for a transformer etc.) and contribute to damp an oscillatory circuit. Also, with a SPICE engine, the integration method influences the result but I am not sure with SIMPLIS as they don't disclose much about their engine operation.

Comment: @VerbalKint, Yes, I agree with you, but in reality, the SR  does have a Coss (output capacitance) associated with it. I just don't understand why considering this Coss would cause significant ringing in the VLm (magnetizing voltage) even I also add some loss resistor in there.